# POD error . Pod relies on the removed \`pre_install\` or \`post_install\`

Tags: xcode, facebook, cocoapods

When I try to install pods. It says,

```
Installing AFNetworking 2.0.0-RC3 (was 2.0.0-RC3)
Installing Bolts (1.1.0)
Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK 3.14.1 (was 3.8.0)
Installing FontAwesomeKit (2.1.5)
Installing FontasticIcons 0.5.0 (was 0.5.0)
Installing JXHTTP (1.0.0)
Installing MBProgressHUD 0.8 (was 0.8)
Installing NSData+Base64 (1.0.0)
Installing RNFrostedSidebar (0.2.0)
Installing SSToolkit 1.0.4 (was 1.0.4)
[!] /bin/bash 
set -e
echo "This Pod relies on the removed \`pre_install\` or \`post_install\` hooks and therefore will no longer continue to work. Please try updating to the latest version of this Pod or updating the Pod specification. See http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Trunk/ for more details." && exit 1

This Pod relies on the removed `pre_install` or `post_install` hooks and therefore will no longer continue to work. Please try updating to the latest version of this Pod or updating the Pod specification. See http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Trunk/ for more details.
```

Anybody idea, what to do correct this bug. is this related to pods OR any particular repo. ?

Comment: The issue is not with pods , i am able to use it in another project.

Comment: Hi the issue is that the Pod you are using hasn't been updated. It won't work until the developer of the Pod has updated the Podspec.

See this issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2155

Comment: yeah, i guess its updated , so its gone. otherwise this is not under control of person who is using the pod.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is coming from SSToolkit only. The solution found here: https://github.com/soffes/sstoolkit/issues/197 also worked for me. Namely, in your Podfile, replace the SSToolkit line with this one:

```
 pod 'SSToolkit', :git => 'https://github.com/soffes/sstoolkit.git', :commit => '1403f02cb98f8357f4b8e43c59d9c69d608d7bed'
```